# Can I change ranger's delete command to move command?

Tags: shortcut-keys, filemanager, delete

Is it possible to change ranger delete (d, D) command to moving to Downloads directory?
I've written own script what delete from this directory all old files, so it's sth like trash bin directory.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can, since you can change keybindings in ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can change keybindings in `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`. To change the assignment of the delete command, dD, you can specify

```
map DD shell mv %s /home/${USER}/.local/share/Trash/files/
```

To "delete" files to the trash. Substitute any other destination if you feel like so.